# Downloading and installing Flex and Bison for use in closed environment (can not use apt-get)

Tags: software-installation, bison

I am trying to download and install **Flex** and **Bison** for use in a closed environment on a new install of ubuntu. I have searched and can not seem to figure out exactly WHAT I need to download.

Comment: To do what? [flex](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=flex&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) and [bison]http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=bison&searchon=names are avilable in the repositories. Please help us help you by reviewing http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and [edit]ing your post to indicate what you wanted, what you tried, and what happened when you did. Thank you!

Comment: If you're open to Apt packages (in this case, `flex` and `bison`) but just not an Internet connection, [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline) is similar and offers several options.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. However, trying to install them on a closed network is proving to be more of a problem for me than probably should be. I downloaded the correct files and uploaded to my closed system but when I attempt install it stills calls out for an internet connection.

Comment: You can edit your question to add additional information.  What files did you download, and how did you try to install them?

Answer (score 0):

On a system with internet connectivity, download the flex and bison packages:

```
apt-get download flex bison
```

Bring those deb files (flex_2.6.0-11_amd64.deb and bison_2%3a3.0.4.dfsg-1_amd64.deb) to your closed system.
Install them from a terminal, whose current directory is the location of the deb files:

```
sudo dpkg -i flex_2.6.0-11_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i bison_2%3a3.0.4.dfsg-1_amd64.deb
```

If you had tried to use Nautilus to install the package, the "Open with Software Install" R. click menu choice does require a network connection.